# remove cakephp 3 foldername from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, url-rewriting, routes

I want to change the URL from:

```
www.example.com/api/
```

To:

```
www.example.com/
```

in which api folder i installed cakephp 3 and its working fine.

i want to remove api in the url and after this it looks like www.example.com.can someone please help me how to do this i don't want to change files from api folder to root directory.
my api folder .htaccess is like below.

```
**.htaccess of api folder**
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **.htaccess in root (www) folder**  like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    api/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) api/$1    [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: thanks for reply but Controller could not be found.  errors show